# How to Receive dictionary in post data passed in Django Template

Tags: django, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array, request

Below is my model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    number = models.ForeignKey(Admfiles, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  blank = False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255,  blank = False)
    situation= models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = False)
```

In my template, inputs are created dynamically using js append inputs, so I don't know the length of dictionary.

```
<input name="person[0][name]"      value="...">
<input name="person[0][situation]" value="...">
<input name="person[1][name]"      value="...">
<input name="person[1][situation]" value="...">
<input name="person[n][name]"      value="...">
<input name="person[n][situation]" value="...">
```

I receive the correct value if do:

```
return HttpResponse(request.POST.get('person[0][name]'))
return HttpResponse(request.POST.get('person[0][situation]'))
```

How can I iterate to save n element into my Model?

Comment: @Winston Can you help me with my question? I've been looking the answer for hours without results.

Comment: Hi @Marce Laco, Your question is a bit vague. If you could add more details, add your views, or a sample input, we may be able to help you.

Comment: @Winston, sorry I'm new in Django. Is this more understandable now?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I use: `def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = request.POST.dict()
            for key in data:
                value = data[key]` Error message is: **CreatePerson didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

Comment: @Winston any ideas? Sorry, my brain is going to explode!

Comment: How about using `request.data` instead of `request.POST.dict()`?

Comment: @Winston I really apreciatte your concern. Finally I found the solution using inline_formset as below. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here][1]

I finally used formset library. (pip install... as first step)

Setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'djangoformsetjs',
]
```

My forms:

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory

class CrearImputadoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Imputado
        fields = '__all__'

ImputadoFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Expediente,
    Imputado,
    extra=1
)
```

My view:

```
class CrearImputado(CreateView):
    model = Imputado
    form_class = CrearImputadoForm
    template_name = 'crear_imputado.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = ImputadoFormset(queryset=Imputado.objects.none())
        context['expedientes'] = Expediente.objects.filter(id = self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context

    def post (self, request, * args, ** kwargs):
        #return HttpResponse(request.POST.items())
        expediente = Expediente.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('numero_id'))
        form = ImputadoFormset(request.POST, instance=expediente)
        if form.is_valid():
            #return HttpResponse(request.POST.items())
            form.save()
            return redirect('repositorio:crear_delito', request.POST.get('numero_id'))
        else:
            #return HttpResponse(request.POST.items())
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'mensaje':'Ocurrió un error. Contáctese con el administrador.'})
```

Template:

```
            <table class="table table-striped">
                {{ formset.management_form }}
                {% for form in formset %}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    {% endif %}
                    <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row">
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            <td>
                                {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                        {{ hidden }}                                            
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                                {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                {{ field }}
                            </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table> 


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row').formset({
        addText: 'Nuevo Imputado',
        deleteText: 'Borrar',
        prefix: 'imputado_set'
    });
</script>
```

```
And finally import jquery.formset.js.

I don't know if it's the best way, but works fine.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRPaZ.png
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can fetch the entire POST data like below:

```
data = request.POST.dict()
```

Then you can iterate over this dictionary and save the objects.

```
for key in data:
   value = data['key']
   # save the element in your database
```